# How to use ag-grid methods in aurelia framework?

Tags: html, aurelia, ag-grid

I am working on aurelia with ag-grid but if i use the ag-grid methods in aurelia it shows method is undefined.

import * as ag from 'ag-grid';// import the ag-grid method from node-modules

gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter();// this shows on console api and setQuickFilter is undefined.

so., can any one help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that since you are saying `import * as ag from 'ag-grid';` that everything from that file will be aliased with `ag`. Which means that you need `ag.gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter()`.